# Xcode Energy impact very high - Display on iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, performance, energy

I have noticed that for an iPhone X, the Energy impact has another item, Display, and an iPhone 6 plus doesn’t have this.
The problem is the fact that the energy impact tends to decrease on the iPhone 6 plus but on the iPhone X, the percentage of the Display will increase in time compared to the Overhead, or CPU, and the Energy impact doesn’t seem to decrease to a reasonable value.

What can I do to improve this?[image][image]

Comment: The percentage is higher but the overall energy usage is lower, so it is a larger percentage of a smaller number. You will also notice that all of the other categories on the iPhone X are lower because the app  has been running for a long time and is basically idle.  The only thing that is using energy is the display so, of course, the percentage will be higher for display.